# How to call a fragment method from an inner class in kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, inner-classes

I have created a method and an inner class in fragment. However outer class method is inaccessible in inner class of Fragment? How to call outer class method or member in inner class of fragment. Below is my code:

```
class BlankFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    mOrientationListener = OrientationChangeListener(requireContext())

}

fun rotateUI(orientation: Int){
    /// something
}

/**
 * This callback returns rotation angle of the phone, to make it return orientation angles enable it on onStart and disable it onPause
 */
private var mOrientationListener: OrientationChangeListener? = null

internal class OrientationChangeListener (context: Context?) : OrientationEventListener(context) {
    /**      portrait
     * (0, 359)
     *
     * (270)            (90)
     * (land)           (land)
     */
    override fun onOrientationChanged(orientation: Int) {

            // this method is inaccessible
            //rotateUI(orientation)
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For inner class the keyword should be inner not internal and then you can use this to access the method like :-

```
this@BlankFragment.rotateUI
```

Comment: Sandeep Kumar thanks for your answer. I have changed it to inner, it worked. rotateUI is still accessible without using this@BlankFragment indicator for inner class.

Comment: `this@BlankFragment` would only be needed if `OrientationChangeListener` itself had `rotateUI` member which shadows `BlankFragment`'s.